# Numpy gcd function

Tags: python, numpy, greatest-common-divisor

Does `numpy` have a `gcd` function somewhere in its structure of modules?

I'm aware of `fractions.gcd` but thought a `numpy` equivalent maybe potentially quicker and work better with `numpy` datatypes.

I have been unable to uncover anything on google other than this [link](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-June/050833.html) which seems out of date and I don't know how I would access the `_gcd` function it suggests exists.

Naively trying:

```
np.gcd
np.euclid
```

hasn't worked for me...

Comment: I think the `_gcd` function you're talking about is at `numpy.core._internal._gcd`, but it's in pure Python (and so not too speedy) and doesn't handle numpy arrays in any case.

Comment: is the de facto approach to use fractions.gcd? I assume that will be a faster C implementation

Comment: yes, they have, numpy.gcd

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write it yourself:

```
def numpy_gcd(a, b):
    a, b = np.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
    a = a.copy()
    b = b.copy()
    pos = np.nonzero(b)[0]
    while len(pos) > 0:
        b2 = b[pos]
        a[pos], b[pos] = b2, a[pos] % b2
        pos = pos[b[pos]!=0]
    return a
```

Here is the code to test the result and speed:

```
In [181]:
n = 2000
a = np.random.randint(100, 1000, n)
b = np.random.randint(1, 100, n)
al = a.tolist()
bl = b.tolist()
cl = zip(al, bl)
from fractions import gcd
g1 = numpy_gcd(a, b)
g2 = [gcd(x, y) for x, y in cl]
print np.all(g1 == g2)

True

In [182]:
%timeit numpy_gcd(a, b)

1000 loops, best of 3: 721 us per loop

In [183]:
%timeit [gcd(x, y) for x, y in cl]

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.64 ms per loop
```

Comment: two and a bit times quicker for your numpy version

Comment: the function you wrote doesn't work for numpy_gcd(10, 5) or am I doing something wrong? I get 0-d arrays can't be indexed

Comment: Its because the function expects numpy arrays (and probably numpy scalars). You should be able to do numpy_gcd[10], [5]) or modify the function to work directly with Python scalars.

Answer (score 12):

Public service announcement for anyone using Python 3.5

```
from math import gcd
gcd(2, 4)
```

And if you want to write it yourself in a one-liner:

```
def gcd(a: int, b: int): return gcd(b, a % b) if b else a
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems there is no `gcd` function yet in `numpy`. However, there is a [gcd function in fractions module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd). If you need to perform `gcd` on `numpy` arrays, you could build a `ufunc` using it:

```
gcd = numpy.frompyfunc(fractions.gcd, 2, 1)
```

Comment: I'm surprised numpy doesn't contain a gcd function

Comment: Nice. To take the gcd of an entire list, you can use `numpy.ufunc.reduce(gcd, m)` where `m` is the list and `gcd` is as defined in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

The functions [gcd (Greatest Common Divisor)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gcd.html#numpy.gcd) and [lcm (Lowest Common Multiple)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lcm.html#numpy.lcm) have been added to numpy [in version 1.15](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html#new-functions).

You can use them both "as is" on a pair of scalars

```py
import numpy as np

np.gcd(-5, 10)  # yields '5'
```

or on a list or array using `.reduce`:

```py
np.gcd.reduce(np.array([-5, 10, 0, 5]))  # yields '5'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the desired result is not an element-wise gcd but rather the gcd of all numbers in the array, you may use the code below.

```
import numpy as np
from math import gcd as mathgcd

def numpy_set_gcd(a):
    a = np.unique(a)
    if not a.dtype == np.int or a[0] <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Argument must be an array of positive " +
                         "integers.")

    gcd = a[0]
    for i in a[1:]:
        gcd = mathgcd(i, gcd)
        if gcd == 1:
            return 1 

    return gcd
```

Depending on the use case, it can be faster to omit the sorting step `a = np.unique(a)`.

An alternative (maybe more elegant but slower) implementation using ufuncs is

```
import numpy as np
from math import gcd as mathgcd
npmathgcd = np.frompyfunc(mathgcd, 2, 1)

def numpy_set_gcd2(a):
    a = np.unique(a)
    if not a.dtype == np.int or a[0] <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Argument must be an array of positive " +
                         "integers.")
    npmathgcd.at(a[1:], np.arange(a.size-1), a[:-1])
    return a[-1]
```