# Does Python have a function to reduce fractions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numerical, fractions

For example, when I calculate `98/42` I want to get `7/3`, not `2.3333333`, is there a function for that using Python or `Numpy`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `fractions` module can do that

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(98, 42)
Fraction(7, 3)
```

There's a recipe over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569429/numpy-gcd-function) for a numpy gcd. Which you could then use to divide your fraction

```
>>> def numpy_gcd(a, b):
...     a, b = np.broadcast_arrays(a, b)
...     a = a.copy()
...     b = b.copy()
...     pos = np.nonzero(b)[0]
...     while len(pos) > 0:
...         b2 = b[pos]
...         a[pos], b[pos] = b2, a[pos] % b2
...         pos = pos[b[pos]!=0]
...     return a
... 
>>> numpy_gcd(np.array([98]), np.array([42]))
array([14])
>>> 98/14, 42/14
(7, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! The input value has to be integers, cannot be float.

Comment: @LWZ You should be able to use floats as other fractions

Answer (score 8):

Addition to John's answer:

**To get simplified fraction from a decimal number (say 2.0372856077554062)**

Using Fraction gives the following output:

```
Fraction(2.0372856077554062)
#> Fraction(4587559351967261, 2251799813685248)
```

**To get simplified answer** :

```
Fraction(2.0372856077554062).limit_denominator()
#> Fraction(2732, 1341)
```

Comment: Thanks, I now use this by default: even in simple cases, `Fraction` sometimes fails to provide simple answers (1.8 yields 8106479329266893/4503599627370496 instead of 9/5).

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre This might look like a "simple case", but 1.8 cannot be expressed exactly as a binary number; ie, an integer divided by a power of 2. Hence it cannot be represented exactly as a float. A workaround is to use a string instead of a float: compare `Fraction(1.8) --> 
Fraction(8106479329266893, 4503599627370496)` with `Fraction("1.8") --> Fraction(9, 5)`. Note that the denominator 4503599627370496 is 2**52.

Answer (score 2):

Using the math gcd from the math module

```py
    import math
    def simplify_fraction(numerator, denominator):
        if math.gcd(numerator, denominator) == denominator:
            return int(numerator/denominator)
        elif math.gcd(numerator, denominator) == 1:
            return str(numerator) + "/" + str(denominator)
        else:
            top = numerator / math.gcd(numerator, denominator)
            bottom = denominator / math.gcd(numerator, denominator)
            return str(top) + "/" + str(bottom)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does Python have a function to reduce fractions?

No there is no built-in or external function, still you have two solutions.

**1. Using `fractions` module**

You can use `Fraction` objects from `fractions` module. From the documentation:

```
from fractions import Fraction
Fraction(16, -10)
```

`>>> Fraction(-8, 5)`

In this module a fraction is implicitly reduced, you can get the numerator and the denominator:

```
a = 16
b = -10
q = Fraction(a, b)
a = q.numerator
b = q.denominator
print (f'{q} == {a}/{b}')
```

`>>> -8/5 == -8/5`

**2. Reduction using the GCD**

Any fraction can be reduced using the GCD, greatest common factor,  of numerator and denominator: `a/b == (a/gcd)/(b/gcd)`.

GCD function is available both from `numpy` and `math` modules:

```
import numpy as np
a = 98
b = 42
gcd = np.gcd(a, b)
print(f'{a}/{b} == {int(a/gcd)}/{int(b/gcd)}')
```

`>>> 98/42 == 7/3

---

There is an alternative, but I do not consider it as valid for common needs: Use symbolic math with module [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#rational).

This allows to work with exact numbers at the cost of a loss of efficiency. `sympy` is it's own world and some learning time is required.